# How to mask or completely remove Nan values across rows and columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

As I am struggling around this, how to strip/mask or remove all `Nan` values completely across DataFrame so as to see only required values under each column name.

**Dataframe:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("linux_server.csv", usecols=['name', 'managed_by'])
df = df.pivot(columns='managed_by', values='name').rename(columns={np.nan: 'Unknown'})
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract('(.*) ')[0]
df = df.rename(columns={np.nan: 'Unknown'})
print(df)
```

**output:**

```
         Unknown   Audrey Banu Prathap Reddy          Carlton          Eric    Reiner          Krishna  Wilbert      Wim
             NaN      NaN            tdi0960              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN            tdi0963              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN            tdi0966              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN  tdi2513                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN            tdi0765              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN            tdi0969              NaN           NaN       NaN         tdi2479      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN            tdi0970              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN            tdi2431              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN   tdi0424             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2459      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN   tdi0425             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2460      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2461      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2462      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2463      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN          tdi2546           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2464      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN   tdi0426             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN   tdi1874             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2465      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2466      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2467      NaN
 tsnpt01labt004v      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN  tdi2468      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN  tdi2263
 tsnpt01labt005v      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN  tdi2264
         tdi0897      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
 tsnpt01labt003v      NaN                NaN              NaN           NaN       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
             NaN      NaN                NaN              NaN    vms-wan-cs       NaN             NaN      NaN      NaN
```

**Required:**

Output without `Nan` or empty cells.

Below is just sample for three columns as desired

```
  Unknown               Audrey          Banu Prathap Reddy 
 tsnpt01labt004v        tdi2513         tdi0960               
 tsnpt01labt005v                        tdi0963              
 tdi0897                                tdi0966              
 tsnpt01labt003v                        tdi0765                 
                                        tdi0969              
                                        tdi0970              
                                        tdi2431
```

Comment: "Output without Nan or empty cells.".   Length of columns would be different (amount of non NaN values per column). How would it like to be filled with?  Could you show the sample output?

Comment: @Emma, Let me update the post.

Comment: Updated the desired output.

Comment: *Output without Nan or empty cells*. what should it look like?

Comment: @enke, i just updated the sample output for initial three columns, So, if you look that , you may say `Nan` can become empty cells if we use replace but i want real values to be come first for each column. if i do `df.replace(np.nan, '')` then it will do the Job making it empty however it will lead empty spaces between column values which i dont want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your use-case, I think this is the best you can do:

```
In [2213]: output = pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe

In [2214]: for col in df.columns: # Iterate through each column of df
      ...:      # drop all Nan's from each column and concat it with output df
      ...:     output = pd.concat([output, df[col].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)], 1)
      ...: 

# Replace nan with empty strings in the result
In [2217]: output = output.replace(np.nan, '')

In [2218]: output
Out[2218]: 
           Unknown   Audrey Banu_Prathap_Reddy  Carlton        Eric   Reiner  Krishna  Wilbert      Wim
0  tsnpt01labt004v  tdi2513            tdi0960  tdi2546  vms-wan-cs  tdi0424  tdi2479  tdi2459  tdi2263
1  tsnpt01labt005v                     tdi0963                       tdi0425           tdi2460  tdi2264
2          tdi0897                     tdi0966                       tdi0426           tdi2461         
3  tsnpt01labt003v                     tdi0765                       tdi1874           tdi2462         
4                                      tdi0969                                         tdi2463         
5                                      tdi0970                                         tdi2464         
6                                      tdi2431                                         tdi2465         
7                                                                                      tdi2466         
8                                                                                      tdi2467         
9                                                                                      tdi2468
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank for the answer +1, this looks pretty close, can you explain a bit this?

Comment: @kulfi I've updated my answer with explanations. Lemme know if something's still unclear to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could also `stack` + `pivot`. In order to use `pivot`, we must create groups first by the column names using `groupby` + `cumcount`.

```
s = df.replace('Nan', float('nan')).stack()
out = (s.droplevel(0).reset_index(name='value')
       .assign(group=s.groupby(level=1).cumcount().to_numpy())
       .pivot('group', 'index', 'value')
       [df.columns]
       .fillna('')
       .rename_axis(columns=[None], index=[None]))
```

Output:

```
           Unknown   Audrey Banu_Prathap_Reddy  Carlton        Eric   Reiner  Krishna  Wilbert      Wim  
0  tsnpt01labt004v  tdi2513            tdi0960  tdi2546  vms-wan-cs  tdi0424  tdi2479  tdi2459  tdi2263  
1  tsnpt01labt005v                     tdi0963                       tdi0425           tdi2460  tdi2264  
2          tdi0897                     tdi0966                       tdi0426           tdi2461         
3  tsnpt01labt003v                     tdi0765                       tdi1874           tdi2462           
4                                      tdi0969                                         tdi2463           
5                                      tdi0970                                         tdi2464           
6                                      tdi2431                                         tdi2465           
7                                                                                      tdi2466           
8                                                                                      tdi2467              
9                                                                                      tdi2468
```

Comment: @kulfi is your data similar to the sample you provided? This code produces your expected output on the provided sample (did you try it?)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
res = pd.concat([pd.Series(df[i].dropna().values, name=i) for i in df], 1).fillna('')
print(res)
'''
           Unknown   Audrey     Banu  Prathap       Reddy  Carlton     Eric   Reiner  Krishna Wilbert Wim
0  tsnpt01labt004v  tdi2513  tdi0960  tdi2546  vms-wan-cs  tdi0424  tdi2479  tdi2459  tdi2263            
1  tsnpt01labt005v           tdi0963                       tdi0425           tdi2460  tdi2264            
2          tdi0897           tdi0966                       tdi0426           tdi2461                     
3  tsnpt01labt003v           tdi0765                       tdi1874           tdi2462                     
4                            tdi0969                                         tdi2463                     
5                            tdi0970                                         tdi2464                     
6                            tdi2431                                         tdi2465                     
7                                                                            tdi2466                     
8                                                                            tdi2467                     
9                                                                            tdi2468
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with lambda function for remove missing values between non missing and last replace missing values to end of columns:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.dropna().to_numpy())).fillna('')
print (df)
           Unknown   Audrey Banu Prathap Reddy  Carlton        Eric   Reiner  \
0  tsnpt01labt004v  tdi2513            tdi0960  tdi2546  vms-wan-cs  tdi0424   
1  tsnpt01labt005v                     tdi0963                       tdi0425   
2          tdi0897                     tdi0966                       tdi0426   
3  tsnpt01labt003v                     tdi0765                       tdi1874   
4                                      tdi0969                                 
5                                      tdi0970                                 
6                                      tdi2431                                 
7                                                                              
8                                                                              
9                                                                              

   Krishna  Wilbert      Wim  
0  tdi2479  tdi2459  tdi2263  
1           tdi2460  tdi2264  
2           tdi2461           
3           tdi2462           
4           tdi2463           
5           tdi2464           
6           tdi2465           
7           tdi2466           
8           tdi2467           
9           tdi2468
```

Comment: @kulfi - I check accepted answer and get same output, what means `this doesnt pivot as desired` ?

Comment: Jezrael, sorry for the confusion, its working .. thank you so much for explaining and providing an answer .